# Как исправить движение маркеров в яндекс картах v3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, marker

В JS API v3 яндекс карт при добавлении кастомного маркера данный маркер "уезжает" при изменении масштаба, во второй версии для этого было свойство iconImageOffset:

```
var placemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark(
  [37.6, 55.8],
  {},
  {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: '/path/to/icon.png',
    iconImageSize: [20, 30],
    iconImageOffset: [-10, -20]
  }
);
```

в третьей версии, как я понял, такого свойства нет:

```
const marker = new YMapMarker(
  {
    source: 'markerSource',
    coordinates: [37.588144, 55.733842],
    draggable: true,
    mapFollowsOnDrag: true
  },
  markerElement
);
```

Есть ли решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У нас же есть `markerElement`. Все нужные свойства указываются в его стилях:

```js
markerElement.style.height = '30px';
markerElement.style.width = '20px';
markerElement.style.position = 'relative';
markerElement.style.top = '-30px'; // вверх - на высоту маркера
markerElement.style.left = '-10px'; // влево - на половину ширины
const marker = new YMapMarker(
  {
    source: 'markerSource',
    coordinates: [37.588144, 55.733842],
    draggable: true,
    mapFollowsOnDrag: true
  },
  markerElement
);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Использую Next, соответственно при задании стилей top и left всё заработало как надо